# Better way of removing parentheses term in a string?

Tags: mysql

For strings like the following in `Name` field in `Table1`:

`Yada yada (bla bla) yada yada`

The best I can come up with so far to remove the parentheses phrase is:

`Update Table1
Set Name=concat(trim(Substring_index(Name,'(',1)),Substring_index(Name,')',-1))
where Name like '%(%'`

Though this works I am preparing to update a huge table and will be doing so on a regular basis and wondered if there is a more elegant lower-overhead way of doing so?

Comment: since your code is actually working, good job! this looks like a [prime candidate](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to [move](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site#85041) to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No lower overhead way that I've heard of, but the REPLACE function is arguably more elegant, and could handle multiple instances of '(' or ')'.

Comment: @Uueerdo I realize I tried Replace first but was unable to construct it to work. Initially I tried Replace(Field,'(%)','') but that did not work. If you have thoughts on how I can use Replace with substring to get each grouping of () in case there are any (none so far) that would be great but right now limited to the above which works 99% of the time.

Comment: They can be nested `REPLACE(REPLACE(field, '(', ''), ')', '')`